# Is there a way to keep a variable that a generate using Math.random when I run the function multiple times

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a game when you have to guess a number that is generated by the `Math.random()` function in JavaScript. But I realized that when I do that I have to rerun the function if they get the number wrong. Then the number regenerates when it reruns the function. Is there a way that I can make the variable stay until I want to change it. I was going to change it using the `const` function but I realized it would do the same thing. Here is my full code:

```js
var tries = 5;
var howMany = 0;
var wrong = 0;
var player1 = 0;
var player2 = 0;
var triesmulti = 10;
var turn = 'player 1';
var number;

function start() {
    var min = document.getElementById('min').value;
    var max = document.getElementById('max').value;
    number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (+max - +min)) + +min;
    if (tries < 1) {
        alert('You \don\'t have any more tries left. The number was \n' + number);
        tries = 5;
        wrong += 1;
        document.getElementById('wrong').innerHTML = 'You have got the number wrong ' + wrong + ' times';
    } else {
        var guess = prompt();
        if (guess == number) {
            alert('You got the number right!\n' + number);
            howMany += 1;
            tries = 5;
            document.getElementById('howMany').innerHTML = 'You have guessed the number ' + howMany + ' times';
            document.getElementById('tries').innerHTML = 'You have 5 tries left';
        } else {
            alert('You got the number wrong.');
            tries -= 1;
            document.getElementById('tries').innerHTML = 'You have ' + tries + ' tries left';
            setTimeout(start, 1000);
        }
    }
}

function multiplayer() {
    var min = document.getElementById('minm').value;
    var max = document.getElementById('maxm').value;
    number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (+max - +min)) + +min;
    if (triesmulti < 1) {
        alert('You \don\'t have any more tries left\n' + number);
        triesmulti = 10;
        document.getElementById('triesmulti').innerHTML = 'You have 5 tries for each player';
    } else {
        var guess = prompt(turn);
        if (turn == 'player 1') {
            if (guess == number) {
                alert('You got the number right!\n' + number);
                player1 += 1;
                triesmulti = 10;
                document.getElementById('triesmulti').innerHTML = 'You have 5 tries for each player';
            } else {
                alert('You got the number wrong!');
                turn = 'player 2';
                setTimeout(multiplayer, 1000);
            }
        } else if (turn == 'player 2') {
            if (guess == number) {
                alert('You got the number right!\n' + number);
                player2 += 1;
                triesmulti = 10;
                document.getElementById('triesmulti').innerHTML = 'You have 5 tries for each player';
            } else {
                alert('You got the number wrong!');
                turn = 'player1';
                setTimeout(multiplayer, 1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you see there, in the `setTimeout()` it reruns the function.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is easy to accomplish with a closure, but I'd recommend rethinking your design a bit. Avoid globals, duplicated code, manipulating DOM in the same place as your business logic, etc. A bit too broad to offer a full re-write, but once you get it working, consider heading to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @ggorlen I will re-do my code. I guess I will have to do something different.

Comment: You don't have to--you can get it working with what you have. But it's worth thinking about alternate approaches to see if you can organize the application in a better way. The process should be instructive!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a stateful random number generator quite easily with an object or closure:

```js
const rndRng = (lo, hi) => ~~(Math.random() * (hi - lo) + lo);
const intRng = (lo, hi) => {
  let n = rndRng(lo, hi);
  return {
    next: () => (n = rndRng(lo, hi)),
    get: () => n
  };
};

const rng = intRng(10, 20);
console.log(rng.get());
console.log(rng.get());
rng.next();
console.log(rng.get());
console.log(rng.get());
```

But having to do this shouldn't really be necessary for your application. Currently, the application uses [non-idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence#Computer_science_meaning) functions that rely on global state, repeated/duplicate logic and deeply nested conditionals, so it's become too encumbered to easily work with.

I'd start by storing state in an object. A game like this can be modeled well by a [finite state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_finite-state_machine).

The below code is a naive implementation of this with plenty of room for improvement, but hopefully demonstrates the idea. It works for any number of players and it's fairly easy to add features to.

However, string messages are baked into business logic so the class is overburdened. A good next step would be creating a separate view class to abstract business logic from display. However, although the message strings are baked into the game logic, the DOM is decoupled. This makes it fairly easy for the caller to use the class in other UIs such as substituting the DOM for `alert`/`prompt`.

The below solution is far from the only way to approach this design problem.

```js
class GuessingGame {
  constructor(players=1, guesses=5, lo=0, hi=10) {
    this.players = Array(players).fill().map(() => ({
      guesses: guesses, score: 0
    }));
    this.guesses = guesses;
    this.lowerBound = lo;
    this.upperBound = hi;
    this.state = this.initialize;
  }

  initialize() {
    const {lowerBound: lo, upperBound: hi} = this;
    this.players = this.players.map(({score}) => ({
      guesses: this.guesses,
      score: score
    }));
    this.target = ~~(Math.random() * (hi - lo) + lo);
    this.currentPlayer = ~~(Math.random() * this.players.length);
    this.state = this.guess;
    this.message = `guess a number between ${lo} and ${hi - 1} ` +
      `(inclusive), player ${this.currentPlayer}:`;
  }

  handleCorrectGuess() {
    this.state = this.initialize;
    this.players[this.currentPlayer].score++;
    this.message = `player ${this.currentPlayer} guessed ` + 
      `${this.target} correctly! press 'enter' to continue.`;
  }

  handleNoGuessesLeft(guess) {
    this.state = this.initialize;
    this.players[this.currentPlayer].score--;
    this.flash = `${guess} was not the number, player ` + 
      `${this.currentPlayer}.`;
    this.message = `player ${this.currentPlayer} ran out of ` + 
      `guesses. the secret number was ${this.target}. press ` +
      `'enter' to continue.`;
  }

  handleIncorrectGuess(guess) {
    this.flash = `${guess} was not the number, player ` +
    `${this.currentPlayer}.`;
    this.currentPlayer = (this.currentPlayer + 1) % this.players.length;
    const {lowerBound: lo, upperBound: hi} = this;
    this.message = `guess a number between ${lo} and ${hi - 1} ` +
      `(inclusive), player ${this.currentPlayer}:`;
  }

  guess(guess) {
    if (String(+guess) !== String(guess)) {
      this.flash = `sorry, ${guess || "that"} ` + 
        `isn't a valid number. try something else.`;
      return;
    }

    if (this.target === +guess) {
      this.handleCorrectGuess();
    }
    else if (!--this.players[this.currentPlayer].guesses) {
      this.handleNoGuessesLeft(+guess);
    }
    else {
      this.handleIncorrectGuess(+guess);
    }
  }

  nextState(...args) {
    this.flash = "";
    return this.state(...args);
  }

  scoreBoard() {
    return game.players.map((e, i) => 
      `player ${i}: {score: ${e.score}, guesses remaining: ` +
      `${e.guesses}} ${game.currentPlayer === i ? "<--" : ""}`
    ).join("\n");
  }
}

const msgElem = document.getElementById("message");
const responseElem = document.getElementById("response");
const scoresElem = document.getElementById("scoreboard");

const game = new GuessingGame(3);
game.nextState();
msgElem.innerText = game.message;
scoresElem.innerText = game.scoreBoard();
let timeout;

responseElem.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  if (timeout || e.code !== "Enter") {
    return;
  }

  game.nextState(e.target.value);
  e.target.value = "";
  e.target.disabled = true;
  msgElem.innerText = game.flash;
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    msgElem.innerText = game.message;
    scoresElem.innerText = game.scoreBoard();
    timeout = null;
    e.target.disabled = false;
    e.target.focus();
  }, game.flash ? 1300 : 0);
});
```

```css
* { 
  background: white; 
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1.03em;
}

input {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="message"></div>
<input id="response">
<div id="scoreboard"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code is not organised, have lot of duplicates, you could devide it into functions anyway, you can add a boolean variable to check against when you should change the number, I don't know about your HTML code or css but I just added those elements according to you selectors, you can change the multiplayer function too.

```js
var tries = 5;
var howMany = 0;
var wrong = 0;
var player1 = 0;
var player2 = 0;
var triesmulti = 10;
var turn = 'player 1';
var number;
var isAlreadyPlaying = false;

function start() {
    var min = document.getElementById('min').value;
    var max = document.getElementById('max').value;
    if(!isAlreadyPlaying) {
      isAlreadyPlaying = true;
      number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (+max - +min)) + +min;
    }
    if (tries < 1) {
        alert('You \don\'t have any more tries left. The number was \n' + number);
        tries = 5;
        wrong += 1;
        document.getElementById('wrong').innerHTML = 'You have got the number wrong ' + wrong + ' times';
        isAlreadyPlaying = false;
    } else {
        var guess = prompt();
        if (guess == number) {
            alert('You got the number right!\n' + number);
            howMany += 1;
            tries = 5;
            document.getElementById('howMany').innerHTML = 'You have guessed the number ' + howMany + ' times';
            document.getElementById('tries').innerHTML = 'You have 5 tries left';
            isAlreadyPlaying = false;
        } else {
            alert('You got the number wrong.');
            tries -= 1;
            document.getElementById('tries').innerHTML = 'You have ' + tries + ' tries left';
            setTimeout(start, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
  Min <input type="number" id="min" value="1"><br>
  Max<input type="number" id="max" value="10"><br>
  <button onclick="start()">Play</button>
  <p id="wrong"></p>
  <p id="howMany"></p>
  <p id="tries"></p>
```